# C# Allow User to Select and View details of List Object

Tags: c#, list

I have an assignment I need to complete, and I've hit a roadblock at the last part.

I need to allow a user to select an item from a list, and it will display certain elements, in this example the price.

The assignment:

1. Create a text file that will contain the following data related to ice cream toppings for an ice cream store. This file needs to have at least 15 records in it.

---

2. Create Topping Class with the following properties

```
a.   ToppingID
b.   TopDesc
c.    Cost
d.   AmtInInv4
```

---

Main

- a.   You will read in the text file and create objects
  b.  Print out a menu of toppings with Topping ID and Description

  **c.   Allow user to select a topping to get the cost on**

I'm struggling with what's in bold.

This is what I have:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int select, keepGoing = 1;
        string line;
        List<Toppings> toppingList = new List<Toppings>();
        
        

        System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("toppings.txt");

        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            string[] words = line.Split(',');

           
            toppingList.Add(new Toppings(Convert.ToInt32(words[0]), words[1], Convert.ToDouble(words[2]), Convert.ToInt32(words[3])));

        }

        file.Close();

        foreach (Toppings top in toppingList)
        {
            WriteLine("{0,10}{1,25}", top.ToppingId, top.Description);
        }


while (keepGoing == 1)
        {
            select = MakeSelection();
            ShowPrice(ref toppingList[select]);
            WriteLine("Press 1 to enter another item, press 2 to quit.");
            keepGoing = Convert.ToInt32(ReadLine());
        }
       

        ReadKey();

    }

    static int MakeSelection()
    {
        int select;
        WriteLine("");
        WriteLine("To see the price, please select from the menu number: ");
        select = Convert.ToInt32(ReadLine())-1;
        return select;
    }

    static void ShowPrice(ref Toppings topping)
    {
        WriteLine("");
        WriteLine("{0}", topping.Cost.ToString("C"));
    }
}
```

Something like this works when I have an array, but for some reason it doesn't want to work with a List.

I get this Error CS0206 A property or indexer may not be passed as an out or ref parameter

What am I doing wrong? I'm a first year student in C#, so my knowledge is lacking.

Comment: You need to be clearer about what exactly _”doesn't want to work”_ ?... If you are getting an error… what is the error? What is a `Toppings` object and where is a `List<Toppings>` created? I suggest you peruse the SO [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) section as it shows how SO works. The [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may help. In addition, you may find the SO [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) section useful.

Comment: Well, the only “ref” parameter I can see is in the method… `static void ShowPrice(ref Toppings topping)` … here the code is passing in the topping by “reference”?... “why”? This is unnecessary. The code is simply outputting the value from the “topping.” Remove the “ref” in the method signature and where it is called.

Comment: That worked! Thank you! I'm so new to this. Some things make sense to me, and others I hit some walls! Appreciate your help!